# Is there a way to install cx_oracle without root access in linux environment?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Im trying to install cx_oracle with python2.7.11. all the tutorials i found for installing cx_oracle needs root access, however on the vm i dont have root access on the /usr or /etc folders. Is there any way to install cx_oracle in my user directory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply follow these steps:

1. Download the source archive and unpack it somewhere.
2. Run the command "python setup.py build"
3. Copy the library to a location of your choice where you do have access (or you can simply leave it in the build location, too, if you prefer)
4. Set the environment variable PYTHONPATH to point to the location of cx_Oracle.so

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, this works.. followed https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/installing-cx_oracle/

Answer (score 0):

You a Python virtual environment - this way you do not ever need to use System Privs for adding new functionality to your Python Dev Environment.

Look for the command **pyvenv** - there is lots of info on this.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in the below link https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/installing-cx_oracle/

Only thing i ignored was

root> vim oracle.conf

Rest all steps i was able to run without the root access with my user privileges itself.